# Saving variables for later use in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn somehing on neural networks, and I wrote my first program. I would like not to waste all the time which is spent in training the net by saving the adjusted parameters in a file and by loading its later (in an hour, day, or year).
Here's the structure constructor of the Network class, whose wariable I want to save:

```
def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.num_layers = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
             for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
    return
```

and here's my attempt to save and load it,

```
def save(net, name = "noname"):
    with open("{0}_nn_sizes.nn".format(name),"w") as s:
        s.write(str(net.sizes))
    with open("{0}_nn_weights.nn".format(name),"w") as w:
        w.write(str(net.weights))
    with open("{0}_nn_biases.nn".format(name),"w") as b:
        b.write(str(net.biases))
    return

def load(name = "noname"):
    with open("{0}_nn_sizes.nn".format(name),"w") as s:
        net=nn.Network(list(s)) """ERROR HERE"""
    with open("{0}_nn_weights.nn".format(name),"w") as w:
        net.weights = list(w)
    with open("{0}_nn_biases.nn".format(name),"w") as b:
        net.biases = list(b)
    return net
```

which disastrously fails giving an `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` error where pointed.

Actually I'm pretty sure that even the approach is kind of bad, so I'd gladly accept any suggestion or hint on how solve my problem.

Comment: Make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new errors into the code.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it "rovinously fails"? Do you get an error message? Or is the output not what you'd expect?

Comment: Are we supposed to know what "rovinously" means? Has it just been invented?

Comment: The [pickle library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html) might help you with your problem.

Comment: thank you for the feedbacks and the corrections, I edited a bit in oreder to make it more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LaundroMat for his hint, I found a working solution using the pickle library in the following code

```
import pickle

def save(net, name = "noname"):
    with open("{0}.nn".format(name),"wb") as save_file:
        pickle.dump(net,save_file)

def load(name = "noname"):
    with open("{0}.nn".format(name),"rb") as load_file:
        return pickle.load(load_file)
```

Any comment is still appreciate though.